# Влияние народной этимологии на орфографию и морфемику

Tags: орфография, морфемика, морфология

Заинтересовало слово "свидетель".Почему в Викисловаре корень свиде-, суффикс -тель-(по Зализняку) ,хотя логичнее было бы свид-корень, -е-суфф. инфинитива(видеть), -тель- суфф. со знач лица. Посмотрела у А.Тихонова и З.Потихи, в школьном грамматико-орфографическом словаре Текучёва - свидетель - всё слово корень.Поинтересовалась этимологией. Оказалось, оно вообще писалось сведетель. Связано с ве́дать,«знать»; -И- появилось под влиянием слова ви́деть.
Т.е. под влиянием народной этимологии слово стало мотивироваться не глаголом ведать, а глаголом видеть. Интересно, какие слова ещё есть в р. языке, орфография и морфемный состав которых изменились под влиянием народной этимологии? Про морфологию и орфоэпию не спрашиваю, это частое явление ( взять хотя бы кофе - оно).

Comment: Как раз нелогично. В этом случае, слово как бы склеилось в единую сущность. Не уверен, что здесь верно выделять и суффикс -тель-. Скорее все слово корень. Т.к. от него запросто можно образовать целое гнездо слов - свидетельствовать, засвидетельствовать, свидетельство, лжесвидетель...

Наиболее близкое слово - "свидание". Но у него, понятное дело, совсем другая смысловая нагрузка. Так что и корень там будет другой.

Comment: Да в этом-то я как раз разобралась:всё слово - корень - верно и логично(после того как узнала о перемене значения).Нелогично как раз у Зализняка - выделять -тель. Мой вопрос о других словах: есть ли ещё слова , изменившие написание под влиянием народной этимологии?

Comment: Насчет других слов - честно, пока не привели примеры, навскидку вспомнить не буду.

По Зализняку - а Вы в первоисточнике смотрели или только в педивикии?

Comment: В Викисловаре, у меня нет Зализняка, но думаю, искажения нет.А в остальных смотрела на бумажном носителе - везде корень всё слово.

Comment: О том, что свидетель означало раньше "тот, кто знает" - знала и раньше. А вот насчет морфемного состава не задумывалась. Не глядя в словарь. тоже бы выделила суффикс -тель. Мне кажется, это переосмысление значения произошло очень прочно. А следом идет и переосмысление морфемного состава.  Выделяя морфемы, мы все-таки идем от лексического значения. В  настоящий момент, свидетель - это. кто видел. Поэтому я бы разделила на морфемы так:с-вид-е-тель. (пис-а-тель, чит-а-тель, бумаг-о-мар-а-тель). Однокоренные "свидимся, увидимся" - в доказательство приставки)

Comment: Кстати, у Ожегова: сВИДетель -  очеВИДец.

Comment: "Мы имеем дело с живыми словами, в составе которых произошли или происходят исторические изменения; приходится, образно говоря, «резать по живому»: далеко не всегда очевидна грань между этимологическим и современным составом морфов в каждом конкретном случае (ср., например, разный состав слов мыльница, свидетель в Школьном словаре строения слов, Морфемно-орфографическом словаре и в Словаре морфем русского языка".  - из статьи А.Г. Балакай
НЕКОТОРЫЕ СПОРНЫЕ ВОПРОСЫ МОРФЕМНОГО АНАЛИЗА В ВУЗЕ И В ШКОЛЕ

Comment: @Ларf, и как же Вы разберете слово очевидец по морфемам? ;)

Comment: оч/е/вид/ец - это понятно, мотивировано "тот, чьи очи видели". По аналогии с ним я и хотела разобрать "свидетель" - и не получилось, оказалась семантика другой.

Comment: @Людмила, подразумевается наличие двух корней + соед. гласная?

Comment: Да, так, я проверила по словарю строения слов З.Потихи, благо, он под рукой.

Comment: Согласна..

Comment: Словарь древне- и старорусского языка  (Буслаев). Видокъ - свидетель. Корень **вид**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Из "Лингвистических детективов" Шанского.

Правильно ли мы пишем слово **гуталин**?

Вопрос является риторическим. Конечно, правильно, поскольку написание гуталин – единственное, указываемое словарями. Другое дело: соответствует ли это принятое сейчас написание действительной этимологии слова. И вот когда мы начинаем заниматься происхождением существительного гуталин, становится ясным, что современное его написание не первоначально.

В этимологических словарях русского языка слово гуталин не объясняется. Единственным словарем, который дает справку о происхождении этого слова, является «Толковый словарь русского языка» под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова. Однако предлагаемое им объяснение (от нем. gut «хороший») более чем сомнительно. Во-первых, слова на– алин образуются от основ существительных (ср.: нафталин – от греч. naphtha «нефть», формалин – от формальдегид), а во-вторых, все они обозначают химические соединения. О неправильности объяснения этимологии слова гуталин в словаре Ушакова говорит и написание этого слова **в 20-е гг. – гуттолин**. Следовательно, надо искать новое объяснение.

Думается, что наиболее правильным будет такое толкование: существительное гуталин (гуттолин) образовалось в результате сложения лат. gutta «гуттаперча, твердый кожеподобный продукт, представляющий отвердевший сок гуттоносных растений; камень» и лат. oleum «масло» с одновременным присоединением суффикса – ин (< ine) по модели ланолин (от лат. lana «шерсть» и oleum), газолин (от газ и oleum) и т. д.

В современном написании слово гуталин впервые, очевидно, отмечается в «Малой советской энциклопедии» (М., 1929).

Comment: Вы думаете, здесь тоже народная этимология сработала? А может,просто грамматическая аналогия морфов? В любом случае за ответ спасибо. Вот на "Ответах"ещё подсказали:
звездануть (от «звизднуть»), смирение (от «мера»).Оказывается, таких слов тоже много, выходит, я как-то недооценивала народную этимологию .

Comment: смирение - от мера???
И что такое "звизднуть"?

Comment: Да, именно так, посмотрите этимологию слов "смирение" и "звездануть". Для меня это тоже было новостью. А "звизднуть" ( ударить) знакомо, это диалект, но я его от мамы в детстве слышала, только воспринимала как "звездануть", так как мы всегда ищем знакомые слова для объяснения. Так что это именно народная этимология.

Comment: Где смотреть?  
Ни у Фасмера, ни у Крылова, ни у Семенова, ни у Шанского отдельной статьёй нет. А чесать все подряд - это уже слишком.

А, нашел...

смире́нный Из др.-русск. съмѣренъ (Сказ. о Бор. и Глебе 30 и др.), ст.-слав. съмѣренъ ταπεινός (Супр.). От съмѣрити "умерить, смягчить, подавить": мѣра " мера"; с мир сближено по народн. этимологии (Мi. ЕW 195; Мi. LР 938). Ошибочное объяснение дает Маценауэр (LF 11, 169 и сл.)

Ну положим, тут не от "мера" а от умерить... 
Выглядело бы убедительным, если бы мѣр не означало "великий"... Отсюда Владимѣръ.

Comment: Ну, кстати говоря, произошел переход именно ѣ в и.

Владимѣръ -> Владимир.
съмѣренъ -> смирен.

Что-то подобное мы наблюдаем в украинском языке: хлѣбъ -> хліб

Поэтому мне кажется, тут явление более глубокое, чем просто влияние слова с похожим произношением, но немного другим смыслом.

Comment: Спасибо за "Владимира". Это ещё один пример влияния народной этимологии.ВЛАДИМИР- церковнослав. Владимеръ,1 часть – владь – связана с церковнослав."власть", а 2часть родственна готскому mers – "великий". Владимир, таким образом, означает "великий во власти своей". Постепенно слово в народе переосмыслялось, и вторая его часть стала восприниматься как слово мир – "вселенная".
http://www.slovopedia.com/25/194/1649101.html

Comment: gecube, это явления совершенно разного порядка. 
Переход ятя в и в украинском - это нормальный и регулярный процесс, аналогичным переходу ятя в ре в русском. ни с каким переосмыслением не связанный. Владимир же - это совершенно уникальный случай (Со смирением меня отнюдь не убедили, есть же еще родственное примириться и проч, я подумаю ещё). У Владимира же - именно переосмысление. В именах собственных это довольно частый случай, я их жаде в ряд не ставил.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, различия в морфемном анализе при синхронистском и диахронистском подходах настолько велики, что едва ли не любое достаточно древнее слово претерпело переразложение.  Примеры даже приводить не буду.

В отношении изменения правописания. 
Пескарь<пискарь (недавно тут разбиралось),
Синица<(*)сеница - от сень или зень,
близорукий<близозоркий...

Comment: А где Вы нашли синица-от сеница, везде вроде бы объясняется синица - от зиница(от звукоподражания зинь-зинь). Это, конечно, тоже народная этимология, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

На вскидку, слово "зонт" появилось от "зонтик", а то в свою очередь от голландского   "zonnedek"(навес от солнца). Под влиянием народной этимологии у слова выделился суффикс "-ик", который до этого был частью корня.

Comment: А орфография причем?

Answer (score 1):

Моя сельская родня (Тамбовская область) давно-давно говорила что-то вроде: "...а вот надысь свидела, как Ванькя рябятёнка сваво учил...". "Учил" - имелось в виду - "наказывал".А "свидела" - "увидела". По английски -  **eye**witness, witness. Один из русских синонимов - "**оче**видец". Так что - согласен с [@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f).
   А если подразумевать процессуальное, юридическое значение - тогда не исключаю, что корень - все слово.
.

Comment: Спасибо, ребята,всем за ответы. По-моему, хорошо поговорили в новом году, было приятно пообщаться со всеми. @Ларf выбрала не только за сам ответ(хотя он самый основательный), но за беседу в целом, она сразу верно поняла мою мысль и сомнения. Рада была встретить единомышленников.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отличать современный морфемный разбор от исторического, или этимологического. В наше время свидетель имеет только корень -свидетель-, и никак иначе. А этимологически с-вед(Е=>И)-е-тель.

Comment: Вы думаете, авторы различных словарей и научных статей этого не знают? И ведь именно сейчас, к современному значению есть однокоренное "очевидец".